# Wrong texture values in glCopyTexImage2D()

Tags: opengl, textures

I got wrong texture values from glCopyTexImage2D(). I attached depth texture to FBO, and got its value in rendering pass. I expected a result like below : (x : background, y : correct pixel)

```
---yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy-----
-----------yyyyyyyyyyy------
yyyyyy----------y-----------
yyyyyyyyyy-------y----y-yyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy------
```

but, my result is like this :

```
---yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy-----
-----------yyyyyyyyyyy------
yyyyyy----------y-----------
----------------------------
----------------------------
```

From the half of the texture to the end, background pixels are only presented. of course, from the top-left to the half I got a correct result.

a texture creation code is below :

```
glGenTexture(1, &tex);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE, w, h, 0, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE, GL_FLOAT, 0);
```

and in rendering code,

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE, 0, 0, w, h, 0);
```

Is there any mistake in glCopyTexImage2D? w and h is fixed and I don't know why..

Comment: If you're attaching the texture to the FBO, thus rendering directly to it, why are you doing a glCopyTexImage2D?

Answer (score 1):

First, I have no idea how what you've posted compiles as there is no such thing as `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE`. There is `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` however.

Second, you should always use sized depth formats. So instead of `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`, use `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` to get a 24-bit depth buffer. Note that the pixel transfer format (the argument third from the end) should still be `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`.

Third, you should use `glCopyTexSubImage2D`, so that you're not reallocating the texture memory all the time.